# É possível gerar um rota sem passar pela mesma rua novamente?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou usando a API do Google Maps que tem como exemplo o *[waypoints in directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints?hl=pt-br)* para gerar uma rota utilizando vários pontos no mapa. Dependendo do endereço que insiro no mapa, é gerado uma rota voltando pela mesma rua já passada uma vez. Quero de fato desconsiderar que voltando a passar por outra rua o caminho seria mais longo, sendo assim não passando pelas ruas já percorridas.

Veja abaixo um exemplo:

1. R. Ernesto de Castro Neves, 588 - Jardim do Alvinopolis, Atibaia - SP, 12943-270
2. R. Prof. Nilo Andrade Amaral, 230 - Jardim do Alvinopolis, Atibaia - SP, 12943-460
3. Av. Santos Dumont, 342 - Ponte Alta, Atibaia - SP

Abaixo é como é gerado a rota dos endereços acima, considerando o ***endereço 1*** o ponto inicial, o ***endereço 2*** como intermediário e o ***endereço 3*** como final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E agora como eu gostaria que fosse a rota:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível gerar um rota sem passar pela mesma rua novamente?

Comment: Seu problema tem algumas semelhanças com o carteiro chinês...

Comment: Então @JeffersonQuesado, estou dando uma averiguada de como posso implementar isso, que seja do chinês, japonês, indiano, etc. hueha